# What's the ratio $\displaystyle \frac{e^{2(\theta+\phi)}-1}{e^{2\theta}+e^{2\phi}}$ equal to?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm asked what the ratio $\displaystyle \frac{e^{2(\theta+\phi)}-1}{e^{2\theta}+e^{2\phi}}$ is equal to.

The answer I'm given is $\displaystyle \frac{\sinh(\theta+\phi)}{\cosh(\theta-\phi)}$. I could work backwards from this, but how do I show it's equal to this directly?

Comment: Every time I see something like $e^{2x}\pm 1$ I wanna divide by $e^{x}$ to give it a "usual" form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving the N & D  by $e^{x+y}$ $$\dfrac{e^{2(x+y)}-1}{e^{2x}+e^{2y}}=\dfrac{e^{x+y}-e^{-(x+y)}}{e^{x-y}+e^{-(x-y)}}$$

Now use $e^A=\cosh A+\sinh A $